# Websocket in C#, Any nuget package allows changing nic? (network interface card)

Tags: c#, websocket, nic, websocket-sharp

I'm trying to make a C# program which monitors its connection stability to server and switches its network interface card when it seems to be unstable.
So, I was wondering if there is any websocket packages which supports switching nic in C#. 
I am currently using WebsocketSharp in my code, but it doesnt supports the function I need.

Comment: Did you consider doing it at OS level?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions asking for modules, libraries are off topic to this site. Please check [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for further details.

Comment: Not all IP protocols are supported in c#.  For NIC you need to use the Windows dlls using DllImport.  See http://www.pinvoke.net  Try the library : iphlpapi.dll